Set Throttle to 0 for Standard Analog Joystick on Multiwii + NRF24 Drone TX
I've been building a NRF24 Transmitter for my Multiwii 2.3 + NRF24 + BMP180 Drone. Everything looks okay, but when I want to test the NRF24L01 transmitter, I see from Serial Monitor and Mini LCD, It shows 127/128 value for Throttle. Therefore, when I arm the drone and, as soon as I release the left stick (it goes to middle-center position = throttle 127/128), the motors start spin 50% or 127/128.
WHAT TO ACHIEVE:
I want the throttle value go to 0% or 0 or 1 or 10 (even though the left stick is at middle-center position.
Here's the NRF24 Drone code Receiver (related to this case):
1. NRF24_RX.cpp
nrf24_rcData[THROTTLE]  = map(strData.throttle, 0, 255, 1000, 2000);
nrf24_rcData[ROLL]      = map(strData.roll,     0, 255, 1000, 2000);
nrf24_rcData[PITCH]     = map(strData.pitch,    0, 255, 1000, 2000);
nrf24_rcData[YAW]       = map(strData.yaw,      0, 255, 1000, 2000);
nrf24_rcData[AUX1]      = map(strData.AUX1,     0, 1,   1000, 2000);
nrf24_rcData[AUX2]      = map(strData.AUX2,     0, 1,   1000, 2000);

2. in RX.cpp file:
      #elif defined(NRF24_RX)
    if (chan < RC_CHANS) {
      data = nrf24_rcData[chan];
    } else data = 1500;

**FULL CODE for NRF24 TX:**


/*

https://www.youtube.com/@ardujimmy
*/

/******************************************************* Multiwii 2.3 NRF24L01 Transmitter ********************************************************/
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>  
#include <RF24.h>              
  
const uint64_t pipeOut = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL; //IMPORTANT: The same as in the receiver!!!

RF24 radio(4, 3); // CE, CSN

String strAUX1;

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64
#define OLED_RESET -1
#define OLED_ADDR 0x3C

Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);

int16_t tRoll;
int16_t tPitch;

#define trimRollUpPin 8
#define trimRollDownPin 7
#define trimPitchUpPin 6
#define trimPitchDownPin 5

struct MyData {
  byte throttle;
  byte yaw;
  byte pitch;
  byte roll;
  byte AUX1;
  int16_t rollTrim;
  int16_t pitchTrim;
};

MyData data;

void resetData() {
  data.throttle = 0;
  data.yaw = 127;
  data.pitch = 127;
  data.roll = 127;
  data.AUX1 = 0;
  data.rollTrim = 0;
  data.pitchTrim = 0;
}

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(false);
  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipeOut);

  for (byte address = 1; address < 127; address++) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    if (Wire.endTransmission() == 0) {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at 0x");
      Serial.println(address, HEX);
    }

    if (!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, OLED_ADDR)) {
      Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
      //for (;;)
        ;
    }

  display.setTextSize(1);
  display.setTextColor(SSD1306_WHITE);
  //Show in LCD
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setCursor(0, 0); // Set cursor to top-left corner
  display.println("Hallo Ardujimmy");
  display.println("-----------------");      
  display.println("Please wait .....");       
  display.display();
  delay(100);   
  pinMode(trimRollUpPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(trimRollDownPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(trimPitchUpPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(trimPitchDownPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  resetData();    
  }
}

void updateTrimValues() {
  if (digitalRead(trimRollUpPin) == HIGH) {
    tRoll += 5;  // Increase roll trim
  }
  if (digitalRead(trimRollDownPin) == HIGH) {
    tRoll -= 5;  // Decrease roll trim
  }
  if (digitalRead(trimPitchUpPin) == HIGH) {
    tPitch += 5; // Increase pitch trim
  }
  if (digitalRead(trimPitchDownPin) == HIGH) {
    tPitch -= 5; // Decrease pitch trim
  }
  // Constrain trim values
  tRoll = constrain(tRoll, -250, 250);
  tPitch = constrain(tPitch, -250, 250);
}

int mapJoystickValues(int val, int lower, int middle, int upper, bool reverse){
  val = constrain(val, lower, upper);
  if ( val < middle )
    val = map(val, lower, middle, 0, 128);
  else
    val = map(val, middle, upper, 128, 255);
  return ( reverse ? 255 - val : val );
}

void loop(){
      updateTrimValues();
      //data.throttle  = mapJoystickValues(analogRead(A0), 12, 515, 1024, true );
      data.throttle  = mapJoystickValues(analogRead(A0), 12, 515, 1024, true );
      data.yaw       = mapJoystickValues(analogRead(A1),  13, 524, 1024, true ); 
      data.pitch     = mapJoystickValues(analogRead(A3), 10, 512, 1024, true );
      data.roll      = mapJoystickValues(analogRead(A2),  1, 524, 1022, true );
      data.AUX1      = digitalRead(9);
      data.rollTrim  = tRoll;
      data.pitchTrim = tPitch;
      //Send all
      radio.write(&data, sizeof(MyData));
      //Show in LCD
      display.clearDisplay();
      display.setCursor(0, 0); // Set cursor to top-left corner
      display.println("NRF24 BMP180 QuadX");
      if (data.AUX1 == 1){
          strAUX1 = "AUX1 ON";
          }
       else{
          strAUX1 = "AUX1 OFF";
          }
      display.println(strAUX1);          
      display.println("Throttle: " + String(data.throttle));
      display.println("Yaw     : " + String(data.yaw));
      display.println("Roll    : " + String(data.roll));
      display.println("Pitch   : " + String(data.pitch));
      display.println("t_Pitch : " + String(data.pitchTrim));
      display.println("t_Roll  : " + String(data.rollTrim));
      display.display();
      // Add delay for readability
      delay(100);
   }

Perhaps necessary:
Source: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/cfkqHvwNXHw



Re-writing the code map for specific throttle as follows:
int mapThrottleValues(int Throtval, int lower, int middle, int upper, bool reverse){
  Throtval = constrain(Throtval, lower, upper);
  if ( Throtval < middle )
    Throtval = map(Throtval, lower, middle, 0, 192);
  else
    Throtval = map(Throtval, middle, upper, 192, 255);
  return ( reverse ? 255 - Throtval : Throtval );
}

in void loop(), I re-write this:
data.throttle  = mapThrottleValues(analogRead(A0),   2, 128, 518, true );

NOTE: Since I also asked the same question at https://forum.arduino.cc/t/set-throttle-to-0-for-standard-analog-joystick-on-multiwii-nrf24-drone-tx/1335803/15, someone (https://forum.arduino.cc/u/alto777) helps me to give a clue to re-write the code.
Flying test:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOICuyzBk54
Here's the pic, tested successfully~

